# Getting an error of "You need to have Farm administrator privileges to run this cmdlet" in invoking PowerShell script C#

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am currently creating a feature where a user would need to run an existing PowerShell script on button click. However, I am getting an error of "You need to have Farm administrator privileges to run this cmdlet". I have run the code block with elevated privileges already. I have also user Impersonator but there was still an error. My PowerShell script files are location in my Layouts folder. It throws an error at the `powerShell.Invoke()` part.

EDIT: I am invoking a script that would create a subsite (param2) of the param1. `GetPSScriptTopCompanyConifguration(site)` just reads the PowerShell script from the Layouts folder.

this is my code snippet:

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
        {

            string script = GetPSScriptTopCompanyConifguration(site);


            try
            {
                WindowsImpersonationContext wic = null;
                wic = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Impersonate();

                using (PowerShell powerShell = PowerShell.Create())
                {

                    string str = String.Empty;


                    PSSnapInException snapInException = null;
                    powerShell.Runspace.RunspaceConfiguration.AddPSSnapIn(_powershell, out snapInException);
                    powerShell.Runspace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("param1", selectedParam1);
                    powerShell.Runspace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("param2", selectedParam2);


                    powerShell.AddScript(script);

                    try
                    {

                        powerShell.Invoke();
                    }
                    catch (Exception exp)
                    {



                    }
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logger.LogInformation("SPException {0}", ex.Message);
                throw;
            }
```

Comment: What does `GetPSScriptTopCompanyConifguration()` return? We can't really help you if we don't know the cmdlets you're invoking

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen i have modified the question, that method returns the hole script text that the powershell will invoke. hope it was clear

Comment: Using `New-SPSite` or `New-SPWeb`? `New-SPSite` will require Farm Administrator rights, `New-SPWeb` just requires the user to be a Site Collection administrator

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen it's using "New-SPWeb"